# Xcode sometimes doesn't require imports at the top of the file

Tags: xcode

I am faced with a strange issue. I recently rebuilt my Xcode project file using a tool called `Xcode gen`, I now have hundreds of errors in my files related to imports, for example:

```
import Foundation

struct BillingHistoryDetailTableCellViewModel {
  let contentColor: UIColor?
  // Implementation
}
```

error: `Cannot find type 'UIColor' in scope`

Why am I suddenly faced with this error now? Xcode had no issue compiling this kind of file before.

Is there some kind of setting or flag required to fix this?

Comment: Obviously, you need `import UIKit` rather than `import Foundation` if you're going to reference UIKit types. As to why it used Foundation rather than UIKit, if no one chimes in here, you might have to open an issue on that repo. Did it do the right `import` on your view objects? Is the problem just limited to your view model types? (FWIW, view models are generally independent of any UIKit/AppKit types.)

Comment: There are many files in our project like this either not using an import or using the wrong import. They all worked fine until I generated a new `.xcodeproj` file using a 3rd party tool.

The model above is a view model so it makes sense it used `Foundation`, what I don't understand is why it would compile all these files before without any errors....

Comment: “The model above is a view model so it makes sense it used Foundation” ... Agreed. (But, again, forgive the observation, but view models shouldn’t reference UIKit types, IMHO.) Are you saying that your source was always `import Foundation` and you were successfully referencing UIKit types in your non-view objects? You can do that with bridging headers (though not advisable). Or maybe there's some obscure build setting that does that. But generally, if your code references UIKit types, you'd want an explicit `import UIKit`. We really shouldn't be linking every compilation unit with UIKit.

Comment: By the way, no offense intended in the above comments, and if you'd like me to delete them, I'm happy to...

Comment: No offence taken at all.

"Are you saying that your source was always import Foundation and you were successfully referencing UIKit types in your non-view objects" - yes exactly this!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The right solution is to change the source that uses UIKit to `import UIKit` instead of `import Foundation`, to make these hidden dependencies explicit. Or, better, refactor to remove UIKit references from non-view object types. If you are forced to keep all of these undeclared UIKit dependencies, then a bridging header could do that (though, obviously not recommended). There might be other ways to achieve that, too. But I'd consider that only as a short-term patch until you can extricate the UIKit types from the non-view objects.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this for others:

If your project happens to include objective-c code and the bridge file includes imports to frameworks that use `UIKit` then this will be imported globally across your project, hence Xcode not asking for the import in files where you reference objects in UIKit.

This seems kinda like a bad side effect of using an objective c bridge as it's easy to miss the adding the import statements.